# How to set CONNECT_PROMPT of WNetAddConnection2?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, directory, shared

I have C# .Net windows application  and using `WNetAddConnection2` to connect network share folder. I want to validate SharedFolder with username/password with 
access rights. Please refer detail explanation of class at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For `CONNECT_PROMPT`, it is instruction in msdn  that "This flag is ignored unless CONNECT_INTERACTIVE is also set."
My code like

> ```
>  var result = WNetAddConnection2(netResource,credentials.Password,userName,0x00000010//CONNECT_PROMPT]);
> ```

So **Question is how to set both `CONNECT_INTERACTIVE`  and `CONNECT_PROMPT` for class to prompt username and password for shared folder?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `OR` the values together using the `|` operator, e.g.:

```
var both = CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT;
```

Comment: I am using  C# windows application.dwFlags is DWORD and format is 
WNetAddConnection2(netResource, credentials.Password, userName, 0x00000008); Now How can use ‘or’ 
between 0x00000008(CONNECT_INTERACTIVE) and 0x00000010(CONNECT_PROMPT)?

Comment: @MikiShah Simply do `WNetAddConnection2(netResource, credentials.Password, userName, 0x8 | 0x10);`.

Comment: John and Otiel, Thank you very much guys, I have credential prompt now.

Comment: @John can you help me other issue?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159564/prevent-wnetaddconnection2-class-which-allows-prohibited-user-to-access-shared-f#comment21366269_15159564